# Animate HTML5 banner working in everything but Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, jquery-animate, adobe

I created a banner in Animate CC which you can see here:
http://www.dctuk.it/test/trustpilotbanner.html

And it works fine in all browsers.

But when I put it on our beta site (an asp.NET site) it works everywhere except Safari on Mac. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome on Mac but just not Safari (or iPad) and I can't work out why.

You can see it on the site here near the bottom: [link removed]

Does anyone know why this might be? I am thinking it might be nothing to do with Animate and just be a javascript conflict but not sure?

Cheers

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the site your `init()` function gets overridden somewhere near the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( $(window).width() < 480) {     
        $( init );
        function init() {

            // Move the paragraph from #myDiv1 to #myDiv2
            $('#coloursnew').append( $('#imageholder') );
        }
    }
    else {
        //Add your javascript for small screens here
    }
</script>
```

In webkit this function is evaluated even though it is in the if statement and replaces your banner init function:

```
function init() {
    // --- write your JS code here ---

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
```

One solution to the problem would be to replace the code for smaller devices like this:

```
if ( $(window).width() < 480) {     
    init = function() {
        // Move the paragraph from #myDiv1 to #myDiv2
        $('#coloursnew').append( $('#imageholder') );
    };
}
```

Here is a sample [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hp2r233/4/) of the problem. Try it in different browsers to see the result.

Comment: It was my pleasure :)